# Is there a way to have a Gmail account without a mobile number

Tags: google-play-store, google-account

Is there a way to have a Gmail account without a mobile number، To access the Play Store?
I remember there was no such problem in the past.

I am constantly traveling and I do not have a fixed number.

And I'm not interested in constantly creating a new Gmail account with a new phone number. And basically, why on earth you should do something else before doing something (Get a mobile number before an email)?

The funny thing is that you can not even use other email services to access the Play Store without a phone number!، Two verifications, really !?

Therefore, a large number of Android users download their applications from non-standard sites. Maybe hundreds of millions!.

When you enter the Google registration page, you enter everything first, then on the next page, Err, a flag and you have to enter a number in front of it. Why not make such a request on the first page?
You press the next button and you get an error message, yes، you can not have an email address without a mobile number. Why not in America when you can have it even in communist countries?

Besides, In many countries you do not even receive a verification code via mobile number.

Comment: From my understanding the enforced phone number verification is to prevent spammers from creating a large number of Google accounts and then misuse them e.g. via GMail. You can use any phone number you have access to. And having an email address is not a verification at all, you can just buy a domain and run an email server for a few dollar and thus creating an unlimited number of unverified accounts.